# how to retract a fact using clipspy

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

How to retract a fact in CLIPS from a python fucntion using clipspy.
I tried using `build()` but the fact is still there.

```
;;--KB.clp--;;
(defrule main-intent

        (initial-fact)
        =>
        (assert (fact one))
        (assert (fact two))
)

(defrule rule_1
        ?p <- (fact one)
        ?q <- (fact two)
        =>
        (py_pfact)
        (py_retract ?p ?q)
        (py_pfact)
)
```

Run from python

```
# run.py
import clips

clips_env = clips.Environment()

def py_pfact():
    for fact in clips_env.facts():
        print(fact)

def py_retract(p, q):
    clips_env.build('retract '+str(p))

clips_env.define_function(py_retract)
clips_env.define_function(py_pfact)

clips_env.load("KB.clp")
clips_env.reset()
clips_env.run()
```

The output is:

```
(initial-fact)
(fact one)
(fact two)
(initial-fact)
(fact one)
(fact two)
```

(fact one) not retracted. It seems ?p is not containing the fact identifier but the whole fact itself. In the past I have used PyCLIPS in this way and it worked. Is it possible to retracts a fact using ClipsPy?

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `clipspy` the `environment.build` [method](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clips.html#clips.environment.Environment.build) is analogous to CLIPS C API `EnvBuild` and it allows to build constructs such as deftemplates and rules as strings within the engine.

```
clips_env.build("(deftemplate foo (slot bar) (slot baz))")
```

If you want to retract a fact, you can simply call [its method](https://clipspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clips.html#clips.facts.Fact.retract).

```
def py_retract(p, q):
    p.retract()
```